# Unable to access shared folder in one drive for business

Tags: onedrive

We are building an application using onedrive api v2.0.
But we are unable to see/access folders which are shared to user by any other users while making a request to /me/drive/root/children.

Can someone please suggest how to access folders which are shared by someone as our api will further create folders, files in these shared folder.

Answer (score 2):

Shared files don't show up in the user's drive (/me/drive/root in your example) but are available through the sharedWithMe view:

`GET /drive/sharedWithMe`

This returns a collection of items that have been shared with the owner of the drive (or the current user in this case). Each item returned will include the **remoteItem** property which contains a reference to the actual item. If you want to access the actual item, then you need to build a request like this:

`GET /drives/{item.remoteItem.parentReference.driveId}/items/{item.remoteItem.id}`

Which will access the actual shared item (not the link to the remote item which is returned by sharedWithMe).

There's more information about [Shared With Me](https://dev.onedrive.com/drives/shared_with_me.htm) on the OneDrive dev portal.

Comment: Tried to access shared folders using remote items details but we are getting the 404 response from api.

Comment: What app scope is your app using? With OneDrive for Business or SharePoint, Files.ReadWrite will only grant access to the user's data, not to shared data. To access shared files, you need to use Files.ReadWrite.All or Sites.ReadWrite.All.

Comment: We're using the Files.readWrite scope, I'll try using the info you've provided...Thanks..

Comment: tired with new scopes still getting 404, although i was able to access shared folders list using /me/drive/items/sharedWithMe.

Answer (score 0):

The request which was specified by greg works fine. I don't about the scopes specified by gregg, but to access the shared files, you to add the current user through you are making the as secondary administrator to other user ( in this case the user who shared the file) in SharePoint MySite administration.

I suggest to use graph API for accessing files from one drive as the responses are more consistent compared to the response from onedrive api. Though both Ali's require the secondary administrator setting to access the files.